# Is jQuery('.foo').find('.bar') equivalent to jQuery('.bar', jQuery('.foo'))?

Tags: jquery

Using:

```
var $a = $('.foo').find('.bar');

var $b = $('.bar', $('.foo'));
```

I know `$b` will have its context set to `$('.foo')`, while `$a`.  Aside from that, I believe the two objects are the same, correct?

Follow up Qs:

1. Will the perf be the same as well since the search is rooted off of the same object effectively?
2. Does a more strict context improve perf in terms of core jquery operations at all? (I know it's intended for plugin usage.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

yes, they are equivalent, here's the source

```
// HANDLE: $(expr, [context])
// (which is just equivalent to: $(content).find(expr)
} else
    return jQuery( context ).find( selector );
```

To use context effectively, it needs to be an HTMLElement, otherwise the context is `document`

[`find()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) is implemented as such in jQuery 1.3.2

```
find: function( selector ) {
    if ( this.length === 1 ) {
        var ret = this.pushStack( [], "find", selector );
        ret.length = 0;
        jQuery.find( selector, this[0], ret );
        return ret;
    } else {
        return this.pushStack( jQuery.unique(jQuery.map(this, function(elem){
            return jQuery.find( selector, elem );
        })), "find", selector );
    }
}
```

`find()` uses the Sizzle selector engine to do the actual *finding* work (take a look at line 2364 in the jQuery source).

and `pushStack` is

```
// Take an array of elements and push it onto the stack
// (returning the new matched element set)
pushStack: function( elems, name, selector ) {
    // Build a new jQuery matched element set
    var ret = jQuery( elems );

    // Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
    ret.prevObject = this;

    ret.context = this.context;

    if ( name === "find" )
        ret.selector = this.selector + (this.selector ? " " : "") + selector;
    else if ( name )
        ret.selector = this.selector + "." + name + "(" + selector + ")";

    // Return the newly-formed element set
    return ret;
}
```

Brandon Aaron has written a great article on [understanding the context in jQuery](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2009/06/24/understanding-the-context-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the results would be the same.  Performance should be identical as well, but that's what testing is for!

There is a property on the resulting jQuery object which shows the selector used to find the matches.  Check it out in your debugger.  They may even be the same between the two methods.